# Prevent rerendering when specific prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having a reusable component which takes an `editable` prop which can be toggled from outside. The problem is that whenever that toggle is activated the whole component rerenders including API calls which should be only called once. How can i prever rerender if the specific prop `editable` changes? Or what is the way to solve this issue?

What i would like to obtain is to get the API call only once in the component no matter how many times the `editable` prop changes. How can i achieve this?

Code bellow:

```js
export const EditableTableList: React.FC<EditableTableListProps> = React.memo(({ columns, editEnabled, keyName, getData, sendChangeToParent }) => {
...
// THIS RERENDERS EVERYTIME EDITABLE CHANGES
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTableData = async () => {
      setLoadedData(false);
      setOriginalData(await getData());
      setLoadedData(true);
    }

    getTableData();
  }, [getData]);
...
}
```

Comment: By default, in React, when your component's state or props change, your component will re-render. After the render `useEffect` is called always. You should go for `useMemo` hook for a function to be called only when the dependency change.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: `useEffect` is used when the data changes, that's the purpose. You need to remove the API call from the component and put it in the parent. Since it's an async call, your editable will redender when you pass the data from the parent to the editable. Any other change can be listened by `sendChangeToParent`

Answer (score 0):

getData() will re-render every time the parent component will, you could send it as a useCallback function expression so it would retain the same identity even if parent re renders.

Answer (score 0):

The effect is executed again only because your `getData` function is changing - maybe not its content but definitely the instance/reference.

You'll have to memoize it in your parent component, for example using `useCallback`. If you provide the parent component I could give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

By removing **getData** from dependancy array, it may solve the issue.
But to answer the question:

> Prevent rerendering when specific prop changes

You can solve the issue in the following way.

```
function Hello() {
   return <div>component code goes here</div>
}
export default React.memo(Hello, (oldProps, newProps) => {
  return oldProps.prop1 !== newProps.prop1;
})
```